# flowchart JavaScript Library/tool/approach

Tags: javascript, html

### What I am building?

An Web UI interactive question-answered based system. The question would have fixed set of answers. And based on the answer it shall contain another set of questions(based on previous chosen answer)

### Model

Considering the above desired system, it is basically a simple flowchart, i.e a question is a block, and answers take you to another block.

### Problem

I am looking for JS library that builds flowchart iteratively and interactively based on user selection or something similar. Looking into some libraries, either
 1. They are helping in creation of flowchart with Drag'n Drop kind of functionality. (My problem already has flowchart in JSON schema)
 2. Are completely rendering flowchart with all data (via svg)

I need a tool/utility/approach to build flows (of flowchart) via user interaction, i.e question throw ->user selects -> next question thrown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: A flowchart is a visual representation of a series of decisions and steps.  Are you trying to build a visual representation?  Or are you trying to encapsulate the logic in a model?  The question is not clear.  (It would probably be a lot more clear if you showed what you've tried so far.)